# Two Win10 computers, both up to date, run different builds

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

I have two computers, one laptop and one desktop. I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 (from Win7 OEM) a few months ago using the Media Creation Tool. I have now just done an in-place upgrade upgrade on my desktop, and am finding differences between the versions of the operating system. For example, the safely remove hardware icon still uses the Win7 icon style on my laptop, but my desktop uses the Win10 style, and my laptop lacks the "coloured title bars" setting.

Both systems claim to be up-to-date, but it is clear that although they both run Win10 Home 64-bit, they are actualy running different versions. This is confirmed by looking in the settings:

[image: LAptop settings]
[image: Desktop settings]

So the question is why aren't they running the same version, why is the build infomation missing from my laptop settings, and how do I fix this?

### Edit

In response to comment asking for result of winver:

- Laptop: Version 10.0 (Build 10240)
- Desktop: Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.0)

Comment: could your run `winver` on both systems and write what version is showing?

Comment: Have edited question with results

Comment: Was searching the net and it seems you will have to download the 1511 iso and make another in place update.

Comment: Thanks Zina, I will try this after I do a computer backup. I'll check back in on this question when I've tried.

Comment: Thanks, I've reinstalled from a new iso and it's working fine. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I hope you meant an upgrade not reinstall? But great you have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a research on the net and it seems the only solution is to download the 1511 iso and make another in place update.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your laptop doesn't automatically update to 1511.
Try running Windows Update manually from the Settings app.

EDIT: Try this:

- Download the Media Creation Tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
- Run it, and choose "Upgrate this PC", and launch it. It should do everything like if you were upgrading from 7/8 to 10, and it should download the latest version (1511).

Comment: It continues to say that it's up to date.

Comment: @ChristyJames Windows 10 received a build update (more like Windows 10.1, which is different from normal Windows updates, KB-whatsoever) back in November. You can force "reinstall" Windows to update or wait until your OEM or Microsoft gives you an update.